# Posting a letter and sending it via e-mail

Tags: formality, email, letter-writing

I am sending a formal letter to a recipient by registered post and e-mail.

Is it convention to include within the e-mail/PDF such text like: "As sent via post on " or something similar to inform the recipient to also expect the letter via the postal system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done this sort of thing before, and usually just put as my final sentence something like:

> You will also receive shortly a copy of this letter sent by post on
>   18th October.
>
> Regards,
>
> Bill

I would not necessarily say this was 'convention' as such, and though not strictly necessary I would say it is a polite addition to the email.

Comment: More accurate would be "... a *version* of this letter..."; if the printed letter contains the same text it will tell a lie about receiving *another* copy, and if it doesn't contain the same text, it isn't a copy.

Comment: @jwpat7: It might be more "accurate", but such phrasing would certainly look extremely odd to me.

Comment: Technically, it can't be *identical*, because the letter sent by post won't have "You will also receive shortly a copy of this letter sent by post on 18th October."